# SQL where clause that groups columns then values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to know if and how to group where clause statements so that I can type in the first group of columns then the second group like this:

```
... WHERE (column1a,column2a,colum3a) == (column1b,column2b,column3b)
... WHERE (column1a,column2a,colum3a) == ("value1","value2","value3")
```

Instead of this

```
... WHERE column1a = column1b AND column2a = column2b AND column3a = column3b
... WHERE column1a = "value1" AND column2a = "value2"AND column3a = "value3"
```

Just like you can use "REPLACE" instead of "INSERT" to do the same thing.

I want to do this because it is easier for me to pass it in the second form instead of parsing column1b,column2b,column3b or "value1,value2,value3"

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: why not use a join and get them out of your where clause?

Comment: What's the reason you wish to do this? Readability? Easier to build programmatically?

Comment: Not possible, you have to do them separately with `AND` (NOT with ',')

Comment: @TJB That's not entirely true - `MySQL`, for example, does support multi-column `IN` statements.

Comment: @TJB and so does Oracle and Postgresql

Comment: @ClemsonCoder If the only reason you want to do it this way is because it's easier for you to write, I would highly recommend you get used to the actual syntax.

Comment: Okay, I'm updating my question to address y'alls concerns

Comment: how about converting column1a,column2a,colum3a and concate as string and then compate

Comment: I know that INSERT makes you do the whole "a=b , c=d" where as REPLACE makes you do "(a,c) ... (b,d)". 

Thought there might be some alternative WHERE that I don't know about or something.

Comment: @Siyual  (and GurV) I should have specified not in SQLServer....

Comment: @GurV I am using mySQL InnoDB

Comment: @SaggingRufus how do I do that if I am only using values and not a column from another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use multi-column `IN` clause:

```
... WHERE (column1a,column2a,colum3a) in ((column1b,column2b,column3b))
... WHERE (column1a,column2a,colum3a) in (('value1','value2','value3'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it might be it. I will accept this as the answer if it works after I test it out.

Answer (score -1):

You can't group by column with **WHERE** clause, you can use **GROUP BY**.
The **WHERE** clause filter only the records and you can't do this:

```
... WHERE column1a = column1b, column2a = column2b, column3a = column3b
```

But this:

```
... WHERE column1a = column1b AND column2a = column2b AND column3a = column3b
```